# Loop over textboxes by name

Tags: vb.net

The user adds a number (between 3 and 5) in the GUI field `tb_TopicCounts` and based on this number I want to write text the user added into textboxes `tb_topic1, tb_topic2...` into a `List(of String)`. This is what I have tried

```
Dim topicText As New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = 1 To Convert.ToInt16(tb_TopicsCount.Text)
    With topicText
        .Add(tb_topic & i & .text)
    End With
Next i
```

The part `.Add(tb_topic & i & .text)` is not working and I guess it is because it is not a string but I just cannot come up with another way to accomplish this. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: thanks a lot. I could find a solution by myself with the information you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what did the trick:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = 1 To 2
    lst.Add(CType(Me.Controls("TextBox" & i), TextBox).Text)
Next
```